# Constructor issues

Tags: java, constructor

I have a homework project that requires me to write a class with two constructors. In this class I want to define a `toString()` method. I want to make sure that the `toString()` method is defined no matter which constructor was used, so I added it to my class twice, once for each constructor. But now the compiler is complaining about that, telling me that `toString()` is defined twice. So what's the problem here? How do I make sure all my objects get the `toString()` method no matter which constructor is used?

```
public class LibraryRecord{
    public LibraryRecord(String title, String author, int lccn, String publisher, String date, boolean out){
        BookTitle = title;
        BookAuthor = author;
        BookLCCN = lccn;
        BookPublisher = publisher;
        BookDate = date;
        BookAvailable = out;
    }

    public boolean getBookAvailability(){
        return BookAvailable;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "Title: "+ BookTitle;
        return "Author: " + BookAuthor; 
        return "LCCN: " + BookLCCN;
        return "Publisher: " + BookPublisher;
        return "Date" + BookDate;
        return "Available: " + BookAvailable;
    }

    public LibraryRecord(String title, String author, int lccn, String publisher, String date){
        BookTitle = title;
        BookAuthor = author;
        BookLCCN = lccn;
        BookPublisher = publisher;
        BookDate = date;
        boolean BookAvailable = true;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Title: "+ BookTitle;
        return "Author: " + BookAuthor; 
        return "LCCN: " + BookLCCN;
        return "Publisher: " + BookPublisher;
        return "Date" + BookDate;
        return "Available: " + BookAvailable;
    }

    private String BookTitle;
    private String BookAuthor;
    private int BookLCCN;
    private String BookPublisher;
    private String BookDate;
    private boolean BookAvailable;
}
```

Comment: This questions has absolutely nothing to do with constructors.

Comment: There are two methods for toString() method. That's why you are getting this error

Comment: Did you get the information you needed? Are you clear? Or is there still something that you don't understand about this?

Comment: To those who voted to close as off-topic: there are actually two problems here, both of which can be reproduced and neither of which is a typographical error. 1) OP erroneously believed that methods attach to constructors, not classes; and 2) OP didn't understand correct use of `return`. Both are programming issues. Please reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

this has nothing to do with constructors ,you're defining the same method twice in a class and it's not a overloaded method. so the compiler complains. Also note that both methods have illegal syntax with multiple return statements.

```
public String toString(){
    return "Title: "+ BookTitle;
    return "Author: " + BookAuthor; 
    return "LCCN: " + BookLCCN;
    return "Publisher: " + BookPublisher;
    return "Date" + BookDate;
    return "Available: " + BookAvailable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
public String toString(){
  return "Title: "+ BookTitle;
  return "Author: " + BookAuthor; 
  return "LCCN: " + BookLCCN;
  return "Publisher: " + BookPublisher;
  return "Date" + BookDate;
  return "Available: " + BookAvailable;
}
```

twice.

Not only you should remove one of them, you can't have multiple return statements one after the other, since all the statements after the first return statement are unreachable code.

Change it to

```
public String toString(){
  return "Title: "+ BookTitle + 
   "Author: " + BookAuthor + 
   "LCCN: " + BookLCCN +
   "Publisher: " + BookPublisher +
   "Date" + BookDate +
   "Available: " + BookAvailable;
}
```

EDIT:

It doesn't matter how many constructors you have. You can only have one `toString()` method.

P.S. One of your constructors has an bug, since it declares a local variable instead of modifying the instance variable :

```
public LibraryRecord(String title, String author, int lccn, String publisher, String date){
  BookTitle = title;
  BookAuthor = author;
  BookLCCN = lccn;
  BookPublisher = publisher;
  BookDate = date;
  boolean BookAvailable = true; // change this line to BookAvailable = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the excercise I am supposed to build two different constructors, the 1st inputs 6 things the 2nd inputs 5 and sets the 6th as true! I want to have the "toString" method on both of them! how can I do this?

Comment: @KritonGeorgiou See edit

Answer (score 1):

don't write multiple return statements for toString() method.